# Multisite and symlinks doesn't work

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I just tried to implement Drupal Multi site installation with the link [2 Minute Multisite With cPanel](http://drupal.org/node/960934). We found **Warning: symlink() [function.symlink]: File exists in /home/ioss/ashokks/sites/test1/index.php on line 5**. We are trying to installing the below domain http://test1.ashokks.com/index.php, i have already setup Drupal 7 in ashokks.com, and we add sub domain test1. We want a Multi drupal site **test1**, with the sub domain of ashokks.com

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the folder name **test1** in sites to **test1.ashokks.com**, following what reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817175/drupal-multisite-setup).